# received the following bad status code: 500 Google Earth Engine REST API in Google Colab

Tags: python, rest, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

I have received the following error when running the same Colab script that has been perfectly operational just a few days ago.

```
    353     if response.status_code != 200:
--> 354         raise requests.exceptions.RequestException(
    355             f"received the following bad status code: {response.status_code}\nServer message: {response.json()['error']['message']}"
    356         )

RequestException: received the following bad status code: 500
Server message: An internal error has occurred (request: 2a43f4e9-7ce0-42e3-8a5e-d6dd33b74eb6)
```

I am using the `restee` package which accessess Google Earth Engine via the REST API and Google Cloud.
If anyone experiencing the same issue or has an idea how to bypass the problem please let me know :)

Thanks
David

Tried on different devices, still no solution